# Google SHEET Insert Image using Autocrat

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-api

I'm trying to insert a signature on my certificate in Google slide using Autocrat in Googlesheet. I want it to be automatic print of certificate with my signature so i use autocrat to do it. My problem is i cannot insert the image in my certificate using this command

```
=let(Σ,indirect("G2:G"),
     vstack("BLH Admin Signature",arrayformula(ifs(Σ="Santos","https://drive.google.com/file/d/1k3exl0f5jYGdeoTT5NA2hdaw_9gSpqgv/view?usp=sharing",1,))))
```

when i use the command above it will just display nothing and i already tried removing the "file" and "view" AND PUTTING this command in Column F

```
=let(Σ,indirect("G2:G"),
     vstack("BLH Admin Signature",arrayformula(ifs(Σ="Santos","1k3exl0f5jYGdeoTT5NA2hdaw_9gSpqgv",1,))))
```

and a message in column K show and its said that

> Document successfully created; Invalid image URL
> [1k3exl0f5jYGdeoTT5NA2hdaw_9gSpqgv], make sure that it is public;
> Document successfully merged; PDF created; Run via form trigger as
> christianmendigoria12@gmail.com; Timestamp: Oct 3 2023 3:35 AM

but I am sure that the image URL is correct. Does anyone here already encounter my problem? have i entered the wrong code for the image? or is there another formula i should use?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your situation, in this case, how about using your URL to `https://drive.google.com/uc?id=1k3exl0f5jYGdeoTT5NA2hdaw_9gSpqgv&export=download`? That is webContentLink. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.